# FlexboxLayoutManager setFlexDirection.ROW is not working

Tags: android, android-xml, android-layout, android-flexboxlayout

The problem is that all items show one item per row. like this:

```
|   item    |
|   item    |
|   item    |
```

I want to show them like this:

```
| item item |
|   item    |
|           |
```

I have explicity set the width of items to 148dp. It was working fine in GridLayoutManager when column span was 2 or [dynamic column per row based on their width](https://gist.github.com/yqritc/ccca77dc42f2364777e1) to show as many as the screen width but there I could not center them easily.

After FlexLayoutManager I got this problem. Although when I set the direction to COLUMN the items show attached to left side but still on each row.  I have this RealmRecycleView:

```
   <co.moonmonkeylabs.realmrecyclerview.RealmRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleViewDashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/grid_item_offset"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:rrvIsRefreshable="false"
    app:rrvLayoutType="LinearLayout">
   </co.moonmonkeylabs.realmrecyclerview.RealmRecyclerView>
```

and this is where I set the LayoutManager

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(getContext());
    layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);
    mRecyclerView.getRecycleView().setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

and this is my ItemView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
    layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
    layoutManager.setAlignContent(AlignContent.CENTER);
    layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.CENTER);
```

Comment: I will check soon AlignContent and Items do what.